# end of file unexpected

Tags: error-handling

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool accept{}
{
    cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";

    char answer = 0 ;
    cin>> answer ;

    if (answer == 'y') return true;
    return false;
}
```

A common occurrence is 'syntax error: unexpected end of file' on the line after the code has finished. I am unsure how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a {} instead of () after accept which makes the rest of the code unusable.

Next time you get such a problem which probably can drives you insane try to do sanity checks like rewriting the program which is quite small, or commenting out parts of the code you don't feel secure about, so you can rule out possible causes for the error you are getting.

Comment: thanks, after correcting this the compiler now says:  using: '''command not found
./testloop.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ```
./testloop.cpp: line 5: `bool accept ()' ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before from user6035109 correct your code to match the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool accept()
{
    cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";

    char answer = 0 ;
    cin>> answer ;

    if (answer == 'y') return true;
    return false;
}
```

I notied that you tried to execute your programm with "./testloop.cpp". This will try to run the codefile itself and not the compiled executable.

An example manual:

1. Compile your file with the following command: `g++ testloop.cpp -o testloop` (g++ filename.cpp -o prefered executable name - default is "a.out")
2. Run the compiled binary with `./testloop`

Comment: thank you very much for the response! Very helpful. I will give it a go now.